# After text input model set, Angular search filter breaks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a combobox as a directive, and am having some trouble with it. Its setup so when someone clicks the input, it shows all options in a dropdown, and as you type, it filters the results. If you click on a result, it should populate the input with that value.

Unfortunately, I seem to have done something wrong, so when you click on a result, it populates the field, but if you erase the values of the field, <s>rather than returning to the original search, it now ONLY parses through the result you selected.</s> it shows all the values but typing only searches through values that match the search text AND the previously clicked value.

How the directive is called:

```
<combobox data="combobox.systems" results="systemSearch" placeholder="System"></combobox>
```

Directive html:

```
<div class="combobox" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.value" search-id="search.id" ng-class="{ resultsOpen: showDropdown }" ng-change="revealDropdown()" ng-focus="revealDropdown()" ng-blur="hideDropdown()">
    <a class="dropdown" ng-click="toggleDropdown($event)"></a>
    <div class="results" ng-show="showDropdown">
        <a ng-repeat="set in data | filter: { value: search.value }" ng-mousedown="setBox($event, set)" ng-bind-html="set.value | trustHTML"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive code:

```
directive('combobox', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'combobox.html',
        scope: {
            'data': '=data',
            'search': '=results'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.search = { id: '', value: '' };
            if (typeof attrs.placeholder != 'undefined') 
                element.find('input').attr('placeholder', attrs.placeholder);
            scope.showDropdown = false;
            if (typeof scope.data == 'undefined') 
                scope.data = [];

            scope.toggleDropdown = function ($event) {
                $event.stopPropagation();
                scope.showDropdown = scope.showDropdown?false:true;
            };
            scope.revealDropdown = function () {
                if ((isNaN(scope.search) || scope.search.length == 0) && $filter('filter')(scope.data, scope.search).length) 
                    scope.showDropdown = true;
                else 
                    scope.showDropdown = false;
            };
            scope.hideDropdown = function () {
                scope.showDropdown = false;
            };
            $('html').click(function () {
                scope.hideDropdown();
                scope.$apply();
            });

            scope.setBox = function ($event, set) {
                scope.search = set;
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

I did figure out that changing the setBox method to

```
scope.setBox = function ($event, set) {
    scope.search = angular.copy(set);
}
```

This helped a little, but didn't nearly solve the problem. I've made a Plunker to try to help: http://plnkr.co/edit/wYfveGDYaVUpzcOWDbSz

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
scope.setBox = function ($event, set) {
    scope.search.value = set.value;
};
```

And if you need to keep record of the selected item:

```
scope.setBox = function ($event, set) {
    scope.search.value = set.value;
    scope.selected = angular.copy(set);
};
```

Also, you don't really need to pass $event and set into your setBox method, you could do something like:

```
scope.setBox = function () {
    scope.search.value = this.set.value;
    scope.selected = angular.copy(this.set);
};
```